# check between time and get union time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

i have one array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [starttime] => 08:00
            [endtime] => 9.30:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [starttime] => 10:00
            [endtime] => 11:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [starttime] => 10:00
            [endtime] => 12:00
        )

)
```

i want some thing like remove between time and return union time.
like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [starttime] => 08:00
            [endtime] => 09:30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [starttime] => 10:00
            [endtime] => 12:00
        )

)
```

here 08:00 and 9:30 is single no other is between in them bcz 10:00 - 11:00 is bigger to 9:30. 
and 10:00 - 11:00 is between 10:00 - 12:00 so remove second object just display first and third.
just call like get union time.

**Logic**
**i am think on them and got one logic.

first find smallest startime. and after that check any other value is between this smallest startime to endtime.**

[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/C7owRM)

how can i done this.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: yes, show us,show us, show us!!!!!

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER i just think some logic and find some demo to that http://codepad.viper-7.com/C7owRM

Comment: @SmrutiSingh http://codepad.viper-7.com/C7owRM

Comment: So what's your problem now?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER how to implement my array in given manual value?

Comment: So then read about arrays and how to access them: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and the foreach loop: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it

```
    $array = array(
      array('starttime' => '08:00' , 'endtime' => '09:30')  ,
      array('starttime' => '10:00' , 'endtime' => '11:00')  ,
      array('starttime' => '10:00' , 'endtime' => '12:00')  ,
    );

    $i=0;
    foreach($array as $row){
        if(isset($array[$i-1])){
          $prev =  $array[$i];
           if($row['starttime'] < $prev['endtime'] || $row['endtime'] > $prev['endtime']){
             unset($array[$i]);
           }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
```

You can paste and test code [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php).

OUTPUT

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [starttime] => 08:00
                [endtime] => 09:30
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [starttime] => 10:00
                [endtime] => 12:00
            )

    )
```